# Can you make a report type with two objects that lookup to the same object?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have two objects in my NPSP Salesforce org - Projects and Opportunities. Both these objects lookup to the Accounts object. From my understanding, it is not possible to create a report involving both the objects(projects and opportunities) in the same report.

Is my understanding correct, or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but look into joined reports. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.reports_joined_create.htm&type=5 and the training materials at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/reports_dashboards/reports_dashboards_report_types

Comment: I will do that! Thank you!